# ASP.Net MVC: GetClientValidationRules() not working with list type property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

still got no solution for my situation. i want to validate `checkboxes` by `ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable.`

my `GetClientValidationRules()` function is not getting called because i impose my custom attribute on a list type property in view model.

```
[AtleastOne(ErrorMessage = "Select at least one checkbox.")]
public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
```

if i impose **AtleastOne attrbute** on a property which does not return list then **GetClientValidationRules() function is calling**.

anyone can tell me what is the reason for which `GetClientValidationRules()` function is not calling when working with list type property.

please some one help me with right direction. thanks

### EDIT

### see my model and view model code

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class Hobby 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

}

public class SampleViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Products")]
    public List<Product> Products { set; get; }

    [AtleastOne(ErrorMessage = "Select at least one checkbox.")]
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any Product")]
    public int SelectedProductId { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Male or Female")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

### custom validation code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AtleastOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    // For Server side
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var oHobby=value as IEnumerable;

            foreach (var _object in oHobby)
            {
                Hobby _oHobby = (Hobby)_object;
                if (_oHobby.IsSelected)
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }

        }
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "atleastonetrue",
        };
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

### See how i am generating checkboxes in loop

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <b>Hobbies</b><br />
        @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Hobbies.Count(); x++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, new { @class = "hobbycls" }) @: &nbsp; 
            @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, Model.Hobbies[x].Name) @: &nbsp;
            @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].Name) 
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hobbies)
    </div>
```

### client side code

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('atleastonetrue', [], function (options) {
        options.rules['restrictbackdates'] = { mindate: options.params.mindate };
        options.messages['atleastonetrue'] = options.message;
        options.rules['atleastonetrue'] = options.params;
        alert('hello');
        alert(options.message);
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("atleastonetrue", function (value, element, param) {
        return $('.hobbycls:checked').size() > 0;
    });
});
```

### see the html for checkboxes

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
<b>Hobbies</b><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected" id="Hobbies_0__IsSelected" data-val-required="Please check at least one box" data-val="true" class="hobbycls input-validation-error"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[0].IsSelected">  &nbsp; 
<label for="Hobbies_0__IsSelected">Reading</label>  &nbsp;
<input type="hidden" value="Reading" name="Hobbies[0].Name" id="Hobbies_0__Name"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected" id="Hobbies_1__IsSelected" data-val-required="Please check at least one box" data-val="true" class="hobbycls input-validation-error"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[1].IsSelected">  &nbsp; 
<label for="Hobbies_1__IsSelected">Sports</label>  &nbsp;
<input type="hidden" value="Sports" name="Hobbies[1].Name" id="Hobbies_1__Name"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected" id="Hobbies_2__IsSelected" data-val-required="Please check at least one box" data-val="true" class="hobbycls input-validation-error"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="Hobbies[2].IsSelected">  &nbsp; 
<label for="Hobbies_2__IsSelected">Movies</label>  &nbsp;
<input type="hidden" value="Movies" name="Hobbies[2].Name" id="Hobbies_2__Name">                <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Hobbies" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
</div>
```

1) the main problem is my client side js code is not firing
2) when i debug then notice this function **GetClientValidationRules** is not getting called because i use custom attribute on a property which return list type. here it is.

```
[AtleastOne(ErrorMessage = "Select at least one checkbox.")]
public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
```

so please see my code and tell me what is wrong in it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be the solution for you:

```
        public class AtleastOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute//, IClientValidatable
            {
                // For Server side 
                public override bool IsValid(object value)
                {
                    if (value != null && value != string.Empty)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
                public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
                {
                    return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "atleastonetrue", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
                }
            }



   //For client-side validation to work, you need to include the following script in your view (or in a javascript file that you reference)
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("atleastonetrue", function (options) {
            if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "HIDDEN") {
                options.rules["required"] = true;
                if (options.message) {
                    options.messages["required"] = options.message;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i post my full code. see and tell me what is wrong there.

Comment: i think u post code here which is copied from some other site.